# cURL reconnect to the same url

Tags: c++, curl

When I'm trying to connect to a new url I need to run the program with the new url, the program fails to connect and when I restart the program it will connect.

So what I'm trying to do is reset, all connections and instead of restarting the program just try to connect to the url once and then reset the connection and reconnecting, causing the same effect as restarting the program.

Is there any way to do that? And what causes my program to not load a new url? And forcing me to restart the program to make it work?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
 ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
 return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
 std::ofstream file("source.txt");
 CURL *curl;
 CURLcode res = CURL_LAST;
 std::string readBuffer;

 curl = curl_easy_init();
 while (curl && res != CURLE_OK){

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  if (res != CURLE_OK)
   curl = curl_easy_init();
 }
 file << readBuffer;
 file.close();
 std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
 std::cin.ignore();
 return 0;
}
```

Here I'm trying to use a while loop to reconnect and trying to use *curl_easy_init()* to reset the connection

Comment: What is `res` being set to when it fails?  What happens if you do not call `curl_easy_init()` on each iteration, but just reuse the same `curl` handle each time?

Comment: _res_ is begin set to _CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT_, and I can remove the _curl_easy_init()_, it is the same result.

Comment: At the time of the error, are you able to connect to the same URL with a web browser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect with my browser, the only problem is the program.